# Wampserver services do not start

Tags: mysql, apache, wampserver

I installed Wampserver3 yesterday on my Win7 laptop. After a few hours of troubleshooting (reinstalling, installation of VC versions, etc.) the icon finally went green. Today I rebooted my laptop and unfortunately the icon is red ('None of 2 services is running'). The interesting thing is that I am not even able to install the Apache and Mysql services within Wampserver: the Mysql installation does not start at all, the Apache installation quits after I press ENTER. (Yesterday, when somehow Wampserver managed to run, I did not have these problems of course.)

I have already done and checked these, no improvement:

- None of my programmes uses port 80, and I also tried to change
  the Apache port to 8080. No Skype is running.
- No IIS is running.
- There are no php.ini or my.ini files on the C disk (apart from the ones
  in the wamp dir).
- No firewall blocking on the Wampserver.
- In the Computer Manangement I changed the startup type of wampapache and wampmysqld services to automatic and (in the Log on tab) allowed them to interact with desktop.
- In the hosts file there is only the '127.0.0.1 localhost' line.
- I installed all the VC versions.
- I installed the Wampserver on a root folder on C disk, as required.
- I did not reinstall Wampserver on a previous version.

After a new reinstallation the Apache error log looks like this:

```
[Thu Feb 18 12:54:59.108975 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2924:tid 352] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Feb 18 12:54:59.124575 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2924:tid 352] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) PHP/5.6.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Feb 18 12:54:59.124575 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2924:tid 352] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Oct 11 2015 16:06:02
[Thu Feb 18 12:54:59.124575 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2924:tid 352] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.17\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.17'
[Thu Feb 18 12:54:59.124575 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2924:tid 352] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4396
[Thu Feb 18 12:55:00.096204 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4396:tid 192] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Feb 18 12:55:00.158604 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4396:tid 192] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

I guess these lines appear because I forced the services to run in the Computer Management / Services - there is no reaction if I start them within Wampserver, using 'Start All Services'.

Can anybody help, please? I've been reading forums and troubleshooting tips for hours, and really tried everything I could.
Among others, I followed the instructions of the [wampserver troubleshooting page](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915).

**EDIT:**

I checked the Event Viewer. The only relevant errors were:

> The wampmysqld service is marked as an interactive service. However, the system is configured to not allow interactive services. This service may not function properly.

And the same with wampapache. I followed the instructions of Microsoft to this problem, no improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Try running Wampserver as Administrator.